# NodeJS Synchronize clients

Tags: node.js, sockets, synchronization

I'm using socket.io and nodejs,

I have a server and I use it as my nodeJS server. What I'm trying to do is moving clients according to messages sent as **client -> server -> clients**

For example; client1 sending a message "MOVE-RIGHT" to server. Server redirecting this message to all clients LIKE "MOVE-RIGHT-CLIENT1" and according to this message, all clients starting to move client1 to the right direction.

The problem is, all clients may have different latency according to their network status. For example, if server->client1 communication happens in 50 ms, server->client2 communication may happen in 250 ms. Therefore, client1 does this job nearly 200 ms earlier. So we can say that these two movements are not synchronized because one of them happens earlier than other ones.

As you know latency between clients and server may be different for each clients, and also it can be different for each message for the same client.

My question is, Which method should I use to synchronize these clients, to do their jobs at the same time. Is there any feature of socket.io or nodejs about this? What would you recommend for me?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. Clients send echo packets to server frequently. Server knows each clients' latency. Server also know the upper limit of latency. Let's say 511ms. This means, a client with latency greater than 511ms won't be able to join to the game. Anyway, when message arrives to server, server decreases 511ms with each client's latency. Then, message is sent to each client according to their latency. (511-{latency})ms for each client. That means, the message will be sent to client who has greater latency earlier than others. To make this work, frequently means very often